# Linode Ubuntu 16 for PHP 5?

Tags: linode

I was trying to install PHP 5.x on Linode, but I got error:

> E: Package 'php5-fpm' has no installation candidate

The command line is

> sudo apt-get install php5-fpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with Linode. If you're running Ubuntu 16.04 (not 16) on Linode or anywhere else, PHP 5 no longer is available as they have moved on to PHP 7. If you can, I'd suggest using PHP 7. If not, this answer as details on how you can install PHP 5 from a PPA for use on Ubuntu 16.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/756901/51244

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 has php 7 installed as default. 
Change php version in your command. Here is updated command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

Note **php7.0** in command.